# Создание класса Логарифмическая плавающая точка на Python

Tags: python, float

Я хочу для удобства сделать класс с в котором операции совершаются не с самим значение, а со степенью основания. Пример: (10^2)+1 = (10^(2+1)).

Тут пример кода, того как я вижу реализацию:

```
class LogFloat(float):
    def __init__(self, degree, base=10) -> None:
        self = float(base**degree)
        self.base = base
        self.degree = degree

    def __add__(self, value):
        return LogFloat(self.degree+value, base=self.base)
    def __iadd__(self, value):
        return LogFloat(self.degree+value, base=self.base)
    def __sub__(self, value):
        return LogFloat(self.degree-value, base=self.base)
    def __isub__(self, value):
        return LogFloat(self.degree-value, base=self.base)
    
    def __int__(self):
        return int(self)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self)
```

Но код не работает, либо не дате создавать атрибуты из за наследования float, а если поменять на object то не получается использовать переменную как значение float. Не понимаю как это можно исправить

Comment: Приведите пример как вы пытаетесь использовать объект как значение float. Наследоваться от float тут точно не нужно, имеет смысл добавить property значения, вычисляемое `base ** degree`